# Are the characters at the end chosen for production-related reasons?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, production, casting, avengers-infinity-war

At the end of *Avengers: Infinity War* a lot of characters disappear.

Could this event be related to which actors didn't sign on for other movies? Is there a link between announced movies, end credits, actor retirement, and the event?

Examples:

1. Bucky is announced twice as White Wolf (post-credit in *Black Panther*, then clearly named in *Infinity War*), meaning that he will have this role soon. And he shared the fate of Black Panther. I don't see a better way to connect those two.
2. Doctor Strange has a movie incoming.
3. Shield agent has an incoming series.
4. Vision is dead, but Scarlet Witch disappeared but one must be left alive to to mourn the other, from a narrative point of view. So Scarlet Witch has been chosen too.

Is there any sign out-of-universe that will reinforce the idea that the chosen people were chosen for a production-related reason?

Comment: Who do you mean by "Shield agent"? Do you mean Maria Hill, the woman who appears with Nick Fury in the post-credits scene? How does your final example fit your theory? It seems to be completely unrelated.

Comment: I've also gone through the entire question to improve the grammar, so it should be easier to understand what you're asking now. If you feel like I've misunderstood what you were trying to say, please flag that up.

Comment: @F1Krazy, the last point is just like from a narrative perspective when one of the Julliette & Romoe member die, the other stay to mourn. This alone for me is a strong indicator that The choosen one was has a future. It not more valid or less valid than the 1rst example. It's based on the narrative.

Comment: the list can be long, spiderman has an incomming movie. then it add to point 2

Comment: "when one of the Julliette & Romoe member die, the other stay to mourn" - not being funny, but how familiar are you with the story of Romeo and Juliet?

Comment: Don't spoil the end.. do they both die? but still you understand what I was talking about. They both morn the other one for a short period of time.

Comment: Is this whole question going to be formatted as spoiler? Plus the nature of the question itself invites speculation, there's no definitive answer until the next movie sequel is released.

Comment: My main idea was: They did choose them for a reason, their are no randomness in story telling, actor don't come to the stage and play rock sizzor paper to decide who will survive. They were choosen form a narrative point of view. Is their Evidence From in universe (2.) or out universe that can be apply to every choosen char. I 'am talking only about choosen because the set is more limited.

Comment: @Luciano I don't see how this necessarily invites speculation, it seems a reasonably answerable question.

Comment: @Luciano, fell free to edit the question. For the speculation point, for me this question has partial answer, the example I gave are already one. Even if a definitive question will come in the future. The question is in my head not too board.

Comment: @xdtTransform actually, you can comment on any answers when you're the OP of the question, so I'm not sure why you said you can't...

Comment: @AndrewT., I got a warning and my comment wasn't submit. but i have just try and you are right . So I will blame cache and copy past the comment. I didn't type the same text twice for no reason

Answer (score 5):

The actors for most of the selected characters have already signed on for either Avengers 4, a solo movie, or both. I don't believe there is any correlation between the selected characters, and the characters who are/are not set to appear in a future movie.

That's not to say there are no commonalities at all. Notably:

> Since *Endgame* confirmed that Hawkeye survived, then all six Avengers from the original film (Captain America, Iron Man, Thor, Hulk, Black Widow, Hawkeye) survive the events of *Infinity War*.

Comment: While this may sound as a solid counter example , For me this is a solid example that the choice was production based, if you had to split a group in 2 part the subgroup that share the same 'future' should be in together. I am not seeing sign every where like a conspirationist. But it feels like :"Those 6 together, then you , you and you in the other team". But good point +1

Comment: Most of the Guardians of the Galaxy, except one, were also wiped out.  (I don't count Nebula as one of them)